# How to Select First Date, Previous Date, Latest Date where first date is higher than a reference date

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to SELECT the Latest Date, the Second Latest Date and the First Date FROM a table1 where the First Date is higher than a reference Date found in another table2. And that reference Date should also be the latest from that table2. I have a solution, supposed to be. But the problem is, the solutions will not return an output if there is ONLY 1 record from table1. Example of the tables:

**table1**

```
Reg ID | DateOfAI   | byTechnician
2GP001 | 2015-01-13 | 31
2GP001 | 2015-02-18 | 31
2GP001 | 2017-11-10 | 45
2GP001 | 2017-11-30 | 32
2GP044 | 2017-11-30 | 28
2GP001 | 2017-12-23 | 32
```

**table2**

```
Reg ID | DateOfCalving   | DryOffDate
2GP001 | 2016-01-14      | 
2GP070 | 2016-01-14      |
2GP065 | 2017-04-08      | 
2GP001 | 2017-04-12      |
```

my expected output would be:

```
Reg ID | LatestDateOfCalving   | 1stDateOfAI  | PreviousAIDate  | LastestAIDate 
2GP001 | 2017-04-12            | 2017-11-10   | 2017-11-30      | 2017-12-23
```

I have searched everywhere from the moon and back... still no luck. these are the queries that i have used

the Fisrt:

```
    SELECT b.actualDam,COUNT(x.actualDam) AS ilanba, max(b.breedDate) AS huli, max(x.breedDate) AS nex,MIN(x.breedDate) AS una,IFNULL(c.calvingDate,NULL) AS nganak,r.*,h.herdID,a.animalID,a.regID, IFNULL(a.dateOfBirth,NULL) AS buho
  FROM x_animal_breeding_rec b
  LEFT JOIN x_animal_calving_rec c ON b.recID=c.brecID 
  LEFT JOIN x_herd_animal_rel r ON b.actualDam=r.animal 
  LEFT JOIN x_herd h ON r.herd=h.herdID 
  LEFT JOIN x_animal_main_info a ON b.actualDam=a.animalID 
  JOIN x_animal_breeding_rec x ON b.actualDam = x.actualDam AND x.breedDate < b.breedDate  
  WHERE h.herdID = ? AND x.mateType = ? AND x.recFlag = ? GROUP BY b.actualDam
```

---

and the Second one that I've tried is this code:

```
    SELECT b.recID
     , b.actualDam
     , b.breedDate
     , min(b.breedDate) AS una     
     , max(b.breedDate) AS huli
     , COUNT(b.actualDam) AS sundot
     , b.mateType
     , b.recFlag
     , a.animalID
     , a.regID     
     , h.*      
  FROM
     ( SELECT c.recID, c.actualDam           
            , c.breedDate            
            , c.mateType
            , c.recFlag
            , CASE WHEN @prev=c.recID THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END i
            , @prev:=c.recID prev
            FROM x_animal_breeding_rec c        
            , ( SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0 ) vars
            ORDER BY c.recID,c.breedDate DESC
     ) b 
     LEFT JOIN x_animal_main_info a ON b.actualDam=a.animalID 
     LEFT JOIN x_herd_animal_rel h ON b.actualDam=h.animal            
     WHERE i <= 2 GROUP BY b.actualDam HAVING h.herd = ? AND b.mateType = ? AND b.recFlag = ? ORDER BY b.breedDate DESC
```

Another problem here is the first solution returns a WRONG COUNT. the second solution returns a CORRECT COUNT, however, wrong Dates were returned. I hope you could give me an idea. Thanx in Advance.

Comment: In your 1st query you are grouping an b.actualDam, and then take b.breedDate => which is a random one? Should that be min or max? (Same in field list and join condition). That means your reference date is somewhat random.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out @Martin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query answers your question:

```
SELECT
    RegID,
    LatestDateOfCalving,
    MIN(DateOfAI) AS 1stDateOfAI,
    REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(DateOfAI ORDER BY DateOfAI DESC), ',', 2), CONCAT(MAX(DateOfAI), ','), '') AS PreviousAIDate,
    MAX(DateOfAI) AS LatestAIDate
FROM (
    SELECT
        t1.RegID,
        LatestDateOfCalving,
        DateOfAI,
        IF(DateOfAI >= LatestDateOfCalving, 1, 0) AS dates
    FROM table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            RegID,
            MAX(DateOfCalving) AS LatestDateOfCalving
        FROM table2 GROUP BY RegID
    ) AS tt2 ON t1.RegID = tt2.RegID) AS x
WHERE dates = 1
GROUP BY RegID
HAVING COUNT(dates) >= 3;
```

***Output***:

```
+--------+---------------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+
| RegID  | LatestDateOfCalving | 1stDateOfAI | PreviousAIDate | LatestAIDate |
+--------+---------------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+
| 2GP001 | 2017-04-12          | 2017-11-10  | 2017-11-30     | 2017-12-23   |
+--------+---------------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a66f1/3)**

In a subquery we select `RegID` and `LatestDateOfCalving` from `table2` in order to have a reference date. Then join it to `table1` and flag the record whether `DateOfAI` is ***greater or equal to*** `LatestDateOfCalving` (`IF(DateOfAI >= LatestDateOfCalving, 1, 0)`). We use this subquery in the outer query (`SELECT RegID, LatestDateOfCalving, MIN(DateOfAI) AS 1stDateOfAI, MAX(DateOfAI) AS LatestAIDate, ...`) and select only those records where the `DateOfAI` are at or after `LatestDateOfCalving` (`WHERE dates = 1`, where 1 is the flag where the condition was true) and have at least 3 records (`HAVING COUNT(dates) >= 3`). In the outer query I use the `REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(...)))` structure in order to extract the `previousAIDate` from a comma (`,`) separated list of dates.

Comment: wow! great... just what i needed. thanks for giving me an idea about using a "flag - WHERE dates = 1"... really helped me a lot... you're awesome